# React no duplicate props allowed warning when linking external url as props

Tags: reactjs

How would I go about removing this error when trying to route to an external url?

```
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";
import React from "react";
const Linking = ({ id, text, tag, date, handleDeleteLink }) => {
  return (
    <div className="link">
      <span>{tag}</span>
      <span>
        <a rel={"external"} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={"https://" + text}>{text}</a>
      </span>
      <div className="link-footer">
        <small>{date}</small>
        <MdDeleteForever
          onClick={() => handleDeleteLink(id)}
          className="delete-icon"
          size="1.3em"
        ></MdDeleteForever>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: why do you have the rel attribute twice?

Comment: You are passing the `rel` prop twice to the `a` element. If you need the both pass it like `<a rel="external noreferrer" target="_blank" href={"https://" + text}>{text}</a>`

Comment: To set multiple values you just add them divided by a space. Tho, I'm not sure `external` & `noreferrer` are usually set together

Comment: Thanks, I initially thought it was due to passing the {text} prop twice that was causing the warning. Turns out it was something as silly as passing rel twice *facepalm*